# What does advance='no' mean in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran and I dont understand this line:

```
  write(*,'(a35)', advance='no')
```

in:

```
  program democonvertion

  implicit none

  real :: tc, tf, tr, tk

  write(*,'(a35)', advance='no')
 &      "Enter the temperature in Celcius: "
  read(*,*) tc

  tf = (9./5) * tc + 32
  tr = (4./5) * tc
  tk = tc + 273

  write(*,*)
  write(*,'(4a11)') "Celcius","Farenheit","Reamur","Kelvin"
  write(*,'(4f11.2)') tc, tf, tr, tk

  end program democonvertion
```

I already compiled this code and it works. But I still don't understand.

Comment: What exact line are you confused with?  You provided many lines of code from an entire program.

Comment: write(*,'(a35)', advance='no')

Comment: [check](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/f90/lectures/22.html)

Comment: @Durga Your edit destroyed the code and should have never been approved. Please do not change indentation in Fortran codes if you do not know what you are doing. The whole edit history of this post is strange.

Comment: @mr.taco Are you sure you have searched here firat or that you read the questions which the website suggested to you when you entered the title? It was treated many times.

Answer (score 8):

`advance='no'` means that the `write` statement will not advance to the next record (next line) after finishing the writing.

See [Supressing line breaks in Fortran 95 write statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661975/supressing-line-breaks-in-fortran-95-write-statements)
and other related questions and answers.