# Writing data in a line

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to write a variable z in a line in fortran. As you can see, z is the product of g*h. The problem I have is that I would like to print in a line z11,z12,z13,...zn1,x. The first number is the value of i and the second one, the value of j. This is what I have tried:

```
do i=1,ny
  do j=1,nx
     s=xmin + alongintx * (dfloat(j)-1.d0)
     t=ymin + alonginty * (dfloat(i)-1.d0)
     g=(1.d0/(desvestx*dsqrt(2.d0*pi)))*dexp(-(s-amedx)**2/
     $           (2.d0*desvestx**2))
     h=(1.d0/(desvesty*dsqrt(2.d0*pi)))*dexp(-(t-amedy)**2/
     $           (2.d0*desvesty**2))
     z=g*h
     write(45,*)(z,m=1,nx)
   end do
end do
```

The problem is that it prints the same value in a line nx times. How can I solve it without saving data in arrays? I would be interested in treating great amounts of data (nx and ny >10000) so store in array is not an option

Comment: `nx` about 10000 doesn't lead to huge volumes of data, but if you are still against that then you may be interested in _non-advancing_ output.  That's a broad area, so please search here on that concept to see whether it helps.

Comment: On formatting your code here, what you present is not understandable as Fortran: it appears to be a mixture of free- and fixed-form source. Please look again at the code you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `z` is an array with `nx` elements (you forgot to show declarations), then your `write` statement should be

```
write(45,*) (z(m), m = 1, nx)
```

PS: Don't use specific intrinsic names.  Use `sqrt` instead of `dsqrt`.  Use `exp` instead of `dexp`.  Don't use `dfloat` as it is unneeded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I am not interested in store data in an array. z is just a variable, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `advance='no'` and specifying a format.
Have a look at [What does advance='no' mean in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396349/what-does-advance-no-mean-in-fortran)
Something like:

```
write(45,'f13.27',advance='no') z
```

should do the trick.

Playing on `f13.27` should allow you to deal with the spaces between the output.

Comment: It works!! What about if I want to print n values of z in a line and then pass to the next line, writing other n values, and so...?

Comment: Just write an empy character like write(45,'a1') ' ' to switch to the next line or write(45,'a1',advance='no') '\n'